# How to create fancy table of equations (to be typeset before the equations are rendered in text)

Tags: table-of-contents, equations, auxiliary-files

Is there a way to create a command which adds to a table or otherwise typesets in a place specified by the user? Example of what I'm after

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofequations

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi} = -1
\end{equation}\rememberequation{e^{i\pi}=-1}{Euler's Equation}

\end{document}
```

Where the `\tableofequations` command would render something like

```
%with \usepackage{array}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{m{0.3\linewidth} m{0.3\linewidth} m{0.3\linewidth}}
Equation & Name & Page \\\hline
\[e^{i\pi} = -1\] & Euler's Equation & Page 1\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

[image: equation table]

The effect I'm after is *almost exactly* [recorded in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13635/exercises-in-lecture-notes-without-predetermined-placement) with the only difference being the facility to place the equation table before the equation is rendered (as a table of figures renders the captions before the figures are typeset). Possibly to be achevied through an auxilliary file, although I have almost no knowledge of how these work.

Comment: Does [Table of Equations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4954) help you?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'm really after having the equations themselves in the table, and I can't find a way to use `\addcontentsline` to create a table or something similar with the maths in. Maybe an answer based on the source code for `\addcontentsline` would be helpful, but I can't find that either!

Comment: Nitpicking: [Euler's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity) is usually the one involving zero as well, i.e. $e^{i\pi}+1=0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code uses the `.aux` file to store the relevant information. `\rememberequation` both typesets and saves the equation. On the second run, the data is automatically read in at the beginning of the document, building (a long) macro `\listofequations`, which is then used by `\tableofequations` to typeset the table (anywhere in the document).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\rememberequation[2]{%
  \begin{equation}#1\end{equation}%
  \protected@write\@mainaux{}
    {\detokenize{\gappto\listofequations}{%
        (\theequation)&
        \detokenize{$#1$}&
        \detokenize{#2}&
        \thepage\\
      }%
    }%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand\tableofequations{%
  \preto\listofequations{%
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
      \#&Equation&Name&Page\\\hline
  }%
  \appto\listofequations{%
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  \begin{center}
    \listofequations
  \end{center}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofequations

\rememberequation{e^{i\pi}=-1}{Euler's Equation}
\rememberequation{e^{i\pi}=-1}{Euler's Equation, again}
\newpage
\rememberequation{e^{i\pi}=-1}{Euler's Equation, yet again}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** the fancy version requested in the comment

So, the idea is that we write equations in the usual `equation` environment and trigger the "remembering"  code by `\caption`. (I believe `\caption` is a better choice than `\label`.)

Before the code, a disclaimer. This is a hack. I have no idea what trouble it might cause in conjunction with some package ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter

\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{%
  \Collect@Body\rememberequation
}

\newtoks\currentequation
\def\rememberequation#1{%
  \typeout{DEBUG: \detokenize{#1}}%
  % #1 starts with \csname equation\endcsname
  \expandafter\currentequation\expandafter{#1}%
  \let\caption\storecurrentequation
  #1%
}

\def\storecurrentequation#1{%
  \protected@write\@mainaux{}%
    {\detokenize{\gappto\listofequations}{%
        (\theequation)&
        $\expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{\the\currentequation}$&
        \detokenize{#1}&% #1 = caption
        \thepage\\
      }%
    }%
}

\newcommand\tableofequations{%
  \preto\listofequations{%
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
      \#&Equation&Name&Page\\\hline
  }%
  \appto\listofequations{%
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
  }%      
  \begin{center}
    \let\equation\relax
    \let\label\@gobble
    \let\caption\@gobble
    \listofequations
  \end{center}
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofequations

\def\caption#1{}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:1}
  e^{i\pi}=-1
  \caption{Euler's Equation}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:2}
  e^{i\pi}=-1
  \caption{Euler's Equation, again}
\end{equation}

\newpage
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:3}
  e^{i\pi}=-1
  \caption{Euler's Equation, yet again}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is incredible, works perfectly. Thanks! How possible do you think it would be to adapt it so that it could be used ala `\label` in figures with captions?

Comment: Re: fancy version, did it compile on your machine? I've just copied the code into a couple of machines and neither will compile, complaining of `missing { inserted` where the `\caption`s are. I tried to fix it but... I really don't understand most of the tex!

Comment: yes it compiles, i've copied it back to check.  if you're using the same file as before, try compiling several times, or manually deleting the `.aux` file.

Comment: Found the problem, had a rendering LaTeX extension running in the background on my firefox and it interfered with the verbatim section. Works like a charm now. Thanks for all your help!